# Website not displaying scroll bar in IE 8 (Not overflow)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, scrollbar, overflow

I researched this problem already, heres what I know: It's most likely a CSS issue. Most answers pointed to removing "overflow" code in the CSS However, I don't have any code like that in my CSS. It seems like the CSS on my website is a bit more complex than the websites that were used in the questions I researched.(I did not do my own coding, I'm just a lowly designer!)

Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Website: www.100apparel.org

Thanks so much :)

PS: I'm also having a problem with my slide show on the main page displaying in chrome. Anybody have any idea why that is happening?

Comment: This might be as simple as resolving your javascript errors, since you have some quite obvious ones (`$(window).addEvent('domready', function(){` should be `$(function(){` or `$(window).load(function(){` if that ancient jQuery version doesn't support it). Use Chrome dev tools or Firefox with firebug (open toolbar with f12) and check the console for errors. IE has developer tools too but they're generally not very helpfull.

Comment: I tried messing with this error (it's a problem with not being able to go to the cart on the homescreen) but I ended up making things worse. I tried adding the $ to function, but that just made it break. When I copy and pasted $(window).load(function(){ over the old text that made it break too. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, sorry =/

Comment: Also as for the errors, I checked it out with firebug, but I could only find that one error using the console error feature on the homescreen. Any reason why I cant see the errors you are talking about? Btw thank so much for your help!

Comment: Check out different browsers. Generally an error in either chrome/firefox is an indication the script written isn't up to par with todays standards, and this could cause other problems. In short, don't ask people to spit through your code, you should minimize the part that are causing the problems to their base elements so you rule out everything else. If you are still having the problem  and you can reproduce it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) you can ask it here. If you cannot reproduce it then the problem is not in the code used to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider putting this in your CSS to force the vertical scrollbar:

```
html {
height: 101%; /* setting height to 101% forces scroll bar to display */
}
```

Comment: So this answer worked. It seems like a non-ideal solution, one that could end up not working on different systems/browsers. However, if it's working right now, it's much better than it was before, so thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add something That I found, the height: 100; solution didn't work for me, and what I actually found is an Windows 8 (IE 10, even rendering in older modes), is the cause of the issue. This behaviour is controlled by:

```
-ms-overflow-style:
```

Listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

your css code looks like this...

```
div.wrapper {
background-color:#F8F8F8;
width: 924px;
_width: 924px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

change it to this see if that helps...

```
div.wrapper {
overflow: auto;
background-color:#F8F8F8;
width: 924px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, I see what you changed, but it seems like instead of the overflow helping the problem, it IS the problem. When I added the code nothing really changed, but I really appreciate your help :)